# Car jerks when dis-engaging clutch quickly

Tags: honda, transmission, clutch, manual-transmission, accord

1988 Accord, 5 speed manual.

If I disengage the clucth quickly the car feels like it jerks. There are no other problems with engaging the clutch or changing gears.

Engine mounts appear ok - I can't see any movement when I have the hood open and am revving the engine. Mounts visually appear fine.

Would anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Sometimes you won't be able to see what's going on with a mount until you check it under load. I think the mount is probably where I'd start. Seeing as how it's an 88, the probability of them being worn out is pretty high.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming everything else is ok, like clutch disk springs, gearbox, differential, and joints, maybe you should change the original rubber engine and gearbox mounts with polyurethane ones. Installing a torque damper also helps.

I own a car repair shop, and I never touched any 1988 Accord (I think I never even see any), but you should find these parts to buy in the US. Here in Brazil, we often make this mounts by torching the rubber off the metal part and press pushing a polyurethane insert in it.